# ruby rescue constant missing?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

few months ago I've been using some ruby library ( I can't recall which one exactly, unfortunately )

I've been surprised to see it allowed me to initialize it's instance with something like that:

```
Lib::SOMETHING(args)
```

I don't really understand how it could possibly work. I'm pretty much sure it should be something dynamic ( there's no SOMETHING constant ) like `constant_missing` module method or maybe the `ConstantMissing` exception gets handled somehow.

Could you please advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No magic there in theory, it just looks unfamiliar:

```
class A
  def self.I_LOOK_LIKE_A_CONST(arg)
    puts arg
  end
end

A::I_LOOK_LIKE_A_CONST("Hi") # => "Hi"
```

`Net::HTTP` does something similar with its `Proxy` class, it allows calls such as `Net::HTTP::Proxy(...)`, it is  defined similarly:

```
def HTTP.Proxy(p_addr, p_port = nil, p_user = nil, p_pass = nil)
```

The punch line is that for class methods you can interchangeably use `::` or `.` to invoke them.

Comment: amazing :) somehow it didn't come to my mind earlier. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I've also discovered there's the const_missing method (works with both class and module) - exact copy of method_missing. I didn't really think such method might be a reality when I posted the question :)

Comment: I suppose you could also use `const_missing` if you needed something more dynamic :). But in the case of Net::HTTP::Proxy there was apparently no need for that.